# Compare two pandas dataframe with different index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two Dataframes

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'cost': [10, 20, 30], 
                     'quantity': [1, 2, 3]})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['B', 'C', 'C','D'], 
                    'cost': [20, 30, 30, 40], 'price': [10, 20, 30, 35], 
                    'serialnumber': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a'],
                    'color': ['red', 'blue', 'green']})
```

I wanted to compare `data1['item']` and `data1['cost']` with `data2['item']` and `data2['cost']`.
If both rows item and cost matches, I wanted to get the `serialnumber` and `price` from `data2` and append in `data1`

I used this python script

```
data1['price','serial']=np.where((data1['item']==data2['item']) & 
                                (data1['cost']==data2['cost']),
                                 data2['price','serialnumber'], np.nan)
```

I am getting an error `can only compare identically-labeled dataframe objects` due to an index mismatch between the 2 dataframes.

Expected Output is

```
  item  cost  quantity  price  serial
0    A    10         1    NaN    NaN
1    B    20         2    NaN    NaN
2    C    30         3   30.0      z
```

Please help me sort this out

Comment: Could you give us a code that create the minimum sample input data for your query?

Comment: I used this code `data1['price']=np.where((data1['item']==data2['item'])&(data1['cost']==data2['cost']), data2['price'], np.nan)` it is working if index is same, but it is not working if index of both files are different. In my scenario, I have different index dataframes

Comment: Never mind, next time you might want to look at here when posting: [how to create a minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - which includes the code for your input data, whatever that it may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use merge function using left key word

```
data1[['price','serial']]=(data1.merge(data2,how='left',on= 

['item','cost']).loc[:,['price','serialnumber']])
```

Comment: "on" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable
I am getting this error

Comment: There was typo in my code, fixed it

Comment: Another error :( `All arrays must be of the same length`

Comment: Your Data2 construction table has an error. It got only three color rows though all other columns has four rows.

Comment: Hi Sajil, One small doubt, If there is some string in cost, then your code is giving NaN for all output, That case how can I manage the cost column in astype()

Comment: you need to transform the "cost" column before you do the new column creation,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253383/discussion-between-moses-and-sajil-alakkalakath).

Comment: code will be   df['cost']=df.cost.astype('int',errors='ignore')